# pdf viewer with preview of internal links for Windows or Linux

Tags: pdf

Is there a pdf viewer with a preview of internal links for Windows or Linux, like in Skim for Mac? (When the mouse cursor is placed on a link, Skim shows its preview in a little pop-up window). I find it VERY useful!

Answer (score 2):

I think that Evince proposes this feature by default now. Unfortunately, I don't think Okular has it.

Comment: Okular really needs this feature